# Installing NVM / NodeJs / EmberJS inside a Vagrant box

Tags: node.js, ember.js, vagrant, nvm

I am having all sorts of fun with this.

The initial issue is that the terminal needs to be restarted after installing NVM so that I can re-initialise with the .bashrc settings and then install NodeJS - so my thinking was that I would build a base box with NVM already installed. That way the terminal will already be initialised with the NVM stuff.

Not the case... Apparently packaging a basebox using Vagrant ignores everything in the /home/vagrant folder. ARRRRRRRGGGGHHHHH!!

REALLY?!!1one

Has anyone had any luck with this? Getting NVM installed inside a vagrant box? or even NodeJs without sudo? It's a horrid rabbit hole atm and I want out!

Comment: Can you share your Vagrantfile?

Comment: We had nodejs/ember-cli running inside a Vagrant box, but could not get livereload to work so we ditched the Vagrant and just run locally, livereload is too important!

Comment: I figured it out. you need to install and configure NVM/NPM and ember before sealing the base box. For livereload you should use NFS and up the watch count for the OS :) I'll try and blog about my experience and report back

Answer (score 20):

I suggest you go back to the shell provisioning strategy , I've also went trough hell with this one but is definitely doable.
After a lot of googling I found that there are two very vaguely documented settings you require for this to work:

First and **the most important part** is that you need to enable the creation of symlinks on the VirtualBox instance with this line on your `config.vm.provider` block, without this NVM just won't work (look in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265091/virtualenv-not-creating-an-environment/21450513#21450513%22here%22)):

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|

  # (...)

  vb.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/vagrant","1"]
end
```

Next you'll have to separate your provisioning script in two parts, one that will run the normal apt/git/whatever stuff as root... and another that will run as the default 'vagrant' user:

```
$rootScript = <<SCRIPT
  # some rooty stuff (just don't forget to include git and curl here)
SCRIPT

## This is the script that will install nvm as the default 'vagrant' user
$userScript = <<SCRIPT
  cd /home/vagrant

  # Installing nvm
  wget -qO- https://raw.github.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | sh

  # This enables NVM without a logout/login
  export NVM_DIR="/home/vagrant/.nvm"
  [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm

  # Install a node and alias
  nvm install 0.10.33
  nvm alias default 0.10.33

  # You can also install other stuff here
  npm install -g bower ember-cli
SCRIPT
```

Last, you need to tell vagrant to run the second script with just user privileges (as almost entirely undocumented [here](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html)):

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $rootScript
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $userScript, privileged: false
```

That should do. Is not pretty but it works.

Check out this [working gist](https://gist.github.com/bbaaxx/d88d433f402539fafc4e) here, and good luck!

Comment: Hey! thanks for that - I ended up just building a basebox with it all installed. I did try something similar with privileged: false - but would never have gotten the setextradata part! I will try with this solution - I can't believe it's so hectic!

Comment: Did you found a chance to test this setup? I had some issues with it while using node-sass but I'm not sure if they are related to the Vagrant Box configuration.

Comment: Wish I could up-vote this 100 times.  Thanks!  This was becoming really frustrating.