# How to create python3 virtualenv on a virtualbox mounted drive shared folder in ubuntu

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04

Im trying to create a python3 virtual environment on a vm virtualbox mounted drive shared folder.

When I try this command

`python3 -m venv sample`

Im getting this error

```
Error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'lib' -> '/media/sf_drive/sample_django/sample/lib64'
```

But Im able to create this under a non shared directory without issues.

How to make this virtual env in a shared directory?

UPDATE:
I have tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24353494/3967750) but Im getting struck with

> Command 'vboxmanage' not found,

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this same issue and was not able to figure out a solution to do it inside the VM.

I ended up creating a symlink on my host OS and then just created the virtual env from the host OS. Then if you go back to your vbox and it'll be there! kind of hacky, but... it works

Answer (score 1):

This is because Windows file system doesn't support symbolic links. You can use:
`virtualenv venv --always-copy` which just copies the files instead of symlinking.